# Migrating services from Server 2003 to Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, migration, windows-server

I need to migrate some services from an old server 2003 to 2012 but cannot figure it out. Below is the screenshot, I'm looking to migrate the Airbus services. Can anyone help?

[image: Image of screenshot of services]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services are not migrated, they belong to a package that you install.

You need to contact the supplier of each service, which is probably Airbus
in your case, for getting the installation media for this package(s).

You will also probably need information on how to register the application
on the Airbus servers, for example login details.